# Is it possible to launch Hearthstone (Diablo, Starcraft, WoW) directly?

Tags: steam, battle.net

Is it possible bypass the Blizzard launcher when starting Hearthstone. I would like to launch Hearthstone directly?

In fact I would like to be able to launch Hearthstone from steam in streaming mode. The Blizzard launcher creates a conflict.

Comment: By extension is could (possibly) also cover Diablo, Starcraft and WoW.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this guide](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/212cyj/how_to_play_diablo_3_without_bnet_launcherget/) for running Diablo 3 bypassing the Launcher.

Basically:

> No Bnet launcher: Go to **Diablo 3** installation folder. Make a shortcut of
>   **Diablo III.exe** (not the launcher) on desktop. Right click the new
>   shortcut->Properties-> Target -> type at the end of the path -launch.
>   It should look like this: "E:\Diablo III\Diablo III.exe" -launch If
>   you want steam overlay: Add a non-steam game. Select Diablo III.exe in
>   the game's folder. In your library, right click Diablo III ->
>   Properties -> Set launch options -> type at the end of the path
>   -launch.

More info on the link above.

Comment: This does not work for Hearthstone, at least not for me on Windows 8. Using this shortcut launches an unresponsive nonfunctional Hearthstone window, which can only be forcefully closed via the Task Manager.

Comment: FWIW, It also does not work with Heroes of the Storm